# How to retrieve image from DB using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I'm using the following code retriever image from DB along with other attributes i.e Full Name, Mobile No. etc.But it is showing an empty image box.

```
require 'database.php';
$MobileNo = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['MobileNo'])) {
$MobileNo = $_REQUEST['MobileNo'];
}

if ( null==$MobileNo ) {
header("Location: index.php");
} else {
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where MobileNo = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($MobileNo));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
Database::disconnect();
}
?>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Picture</label>
<div class="">
<label class="">
<?php

 $row = $data or die("line 44 not working");
 $s=$row['Picture'];
 echo $row['Picture'];

 echo '<img src="'.$s.'" alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:128px;height:128px">';
 ?>

 </label>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `Database::disconnect();` <<< guess what that does.

Comment: Disconnects DB connection

Comment: *There you go* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have disconnected the database before fetching `$row = $data or die("line 44 not working");`

You need to disconnect it after the variable is set.

```
if ( null==$MobileNo ) {
header("Location: index.php");
} else {
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user where MobileNo = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($MobileNo));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$row = $data or die("line 44 not working");
 $s=$row['Picture']; //This is where you make the change. 
 echo $row['Picture'];
Database::disconnect(); //Now disconnect
}
?>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Picture</label>
<div class="">
<label class="">
<?php



 echo '<img src="'.$s.'" alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:128px;height:128px">';
 ?>

 </label>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is there any error? Does the other elements of the page show up?

Comment: All other elements are working fine..Only image box is empty.